# What is the difference between these two methods

Tags: java, object, return, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

These two methods calculate the derivative of a monom, but I dont understand what is the difference between them, do they do the same thing? why does one have a return and the other one makes changes to the calling object?
Which one is better?
In general, how should I return objects?

```
public Monom Der()
{
    double a = this.get_coef() * this.get_pow();
    int b = this.get_pow() - 1;
    return new Monom(a, b);
}

public void Der()
{
        this.set_coefficient(this._power * this._coefficient);
        this.set_power(this._power - 1);
}
```

Comment: Generally you want to avoid opinion-based questions on SO. You should rework your question into something that has a definite answer.

Comment: You understand perfectly. The first creates a `new` object, the second mutates `this` one. The first one is better, if you may require the original values, which get lost with the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one

```
public Monom Der() {
    double a = this.get_coef() * this.get_pow();
    int b = this.get_pow() - 1;
    return new Monom(a, b);
}
```

does not change the state of the instance, it is useful when you want to have immutable objects. It can be used to work with both states the initial state and the state after process

```
Monom initialMonom = new Monom(2, 2);
Monom theNewMonom = initialMonom.Der();
// do something with both initialMonom and theNewMonom
```

This one

```
public void Der() {
    this.set_coefficient(this._power * this._coefficient);
    this.set_power(this._power - 1);
}
```

changes the state of the current instance, so the instance is NOT immutable. It can be useful when the instance needs to be reused

```
Monom initialMonom = new Monom(2, 2);
// do something with initial monom
initialMonom.Der(); // mutate the initial monom
// do something with the new state
```

Comment: Note while it nationally creates an object, short lived objects such as these can be eliminated with escape analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can Google a bit for the details. It's quite many things at the beginning here.

1. Differences: One is returned an Object Monom, one is "void"
2. Why: It depends on your business or the purpose of the codes that you would like to build. Returned Object is used by the next step or just show data. "void" means you don't want to get any data but to do some actions in that method
3. Which is better: It's hard to say. As the previous explanation, it should depend on your need
4. How should you return: refer this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Keep going to search more/practice more. Then it's easier.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The first method creates a new object which will contain the result of the operations, but do not affect the current object, the second one directly changes the object you're using.

Answer (score 0):

While you say that both methods do the same, this it not neccessarily true, since your first method caluclates a result and returns it, your second method calculates the result, but assigns it to a state in the current object.

Lets consider the following class:

```
public class Dinner {

    private Meal meal;

    public Dinner(Meal meal) {
        this.meal = meal;
    }

    public Meal getMeal(Meal meal) {
        return meal;
    }

    public setMeal(Meal meal) {
        this.meal = meal;
    }
}
```

Here, `setMeal` modified the internal state of the object, but it has no return value. On the other hand, `getMeal` return the current state of the object, but does not modify it.

Think about what exactly you need in your use case: If you want to modify internal data of an object, then go with the second way. If you want to return for example, the result of a calculation or internal state, give something back to the caller, so he can operate with it.

In the end, this are just some ideas, implementing a particular problem always comes with a lot of different possibilities so there is no *perfect* answer to this question.